# Does De Moivre's Theorem hold for all real n?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, self-learning

I have seen the proof by induction for all integers, and I have also seen in a textbook that we can use Euler's formula to prove it true for all rational n, but nowhere in the book does it say its true for irrational n.

I have also looked over the internet and there seems to be some problem with non-integer values for n (as I understand, a problem of uniqueness, but I'm not sure).

I would appreciate it if someone could just clarify this for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\cos (z\varphi) + i \sin (z\varphi)$ is for all complex $z$ (why stop at real?) one possible value of $(\cos \varphi + i\sin\varphi)^z$, if that is your question.

Answer (score 6):

The formula is actually true in a more general setting: if $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, then $\left(\cos z + i\sin z\right)^w$ is a multi-valued function while $\cos (wz) + i \sin (wz)$ is not. However, it still holds that $\cos (wz) + i \sin (wz)$ **is one value of** $\left(\cos z + i\sin z\right)^w$.

Comment: $\sqrt{9}=\pm 3$?

Answer (score 0):

In Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, exercise 1.44, it mentions a restriction on $\theta$ for $a \in \Bbb{R}$: $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$. And the example given for this restriction is the case where $\theta = -\pi$ and $a = \frac{1}{2}$.

In such a case, $(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^a = i$, but $\cos (a \theta) + i \sin (a \theta) = -i$.