# A trigonometric identity.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, reference-request, convergence-divergence

I have determined that there is a trigonometric identity (in radians) that goes as follows:

$$(2\cos(n))^k=\cos(nk)+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}(\cos(n(k-2i)))$$

For $n,k\in\mathbb{C}$.

The derivation is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656407/is-there-a-formula-for-sinxy/1659030#1659030) for those who are interested.

I was wondering if this is a well known identity and if there are anything I should note, such as whether or not it will converge.

*Also, as a bonus, I would be happy to see if someone could simplify this into something simpler.*  (Someone had mentioned "De Moivre" expansion, though I don't know what that means here...)

Some links would be nice, as I would like to read about this.

**Update:**

I am rewriting $\cos(nk)=2^k\cos^k(n)-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{i!(k-i)!}(\cos(n(k-2i)))$ so that I may have $\cos(nk)=P_n(\cos(k))$ where $P_n$ is a polynomial, possibly with an infinite amount of terms if $n$ is not a whole number.

Comment: I am consider complex and irrational values for $n,k$.

Comment: There is a lot of material on De Moivre's Theorem. You shouild be able to look it up on your own. The identity !  as it is written gives hint of De Moivre's being quite useful in establishing it.

Comment: Convergence is not an issue.  The sum actually terminates at $i=k$ because of the $(k-i)!$ in the denominator.

Comment: @BarryCipra Actually, it won't if $k$ isn't a whole number, since $i$ must be a whole number.

Comment: @Shailesh Thanks, I found it.  The general idea behind it is very similar to mine and can be shown to become mine... but I have the problem of $n,k$ being irrational and possibly complex.  How shall I proceed with De Moivre's method in those cases?

Comment: @SimpleArt, ah, I didn't notice the conditions on $n$ and $k$.

Comment: @SimpleArt  See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590834/does-de-moivres-theorem-hold-for-all-real-n) for irrational and complex powers. You have to be careful of the multiple branches.