# Why is this proof wrong? ( I proved the irrationality of $\pi$ using the most basic techniques so I suspect that it must have gone wrong somewhere)

Tags: complex-analysis, irrational-numbers, pi

So it starts off by way of contradiction, supposing $\pi\in \mathbb Q$, then by De-Moivre's theorem for rational powers:
$$\left((\cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi)\right)^{\pi}= \cos(2k\pi^2)+i\sin(2k\pi^2)=1^{\pi}$$

Here $k\in \mathbb Z$.

Then you must have $$\cos(2m\pi^2)+i\sin(2m\pi^2)=
\cos(2p\pi^2)+i\sin(2p\pi^2)$$ for all $m,p$ that are integers.

However equating real parts gives $$cos(2m\pi^2)=\cos(2p\pi^2)$$, but this implies that $$2m\pi^2=2t\pi-2p\pi^2\quad  \text {or} \quad 2m\pi^2=2t\pi+2p\pi^2$$

(for some integer $t$)

Which gives that $t= (m-p)\pi$ or $t= (m+p)\pi$; but choosing $m$ and $p$ appropriately such that for
$\pi= \frac ab$ (where $a,b$ are coprime) you have $b$ doesn't divide $m\pm p$, which gives $t$ is not an integer contrary to assumption.
The only remaining case is when $b=1$ which is trivially false as $3<\pi<4$ can be easily proven.

Comment: I'm not convinced that De-Moivre's can be used in this manner, but I'm sure someone will chime in for a definitive answer. [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590834/does-de-moivres-theorem-hold-for-all-real-n) and also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027183/de-moivre-theorem-for-irrational-exponents) and also [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-De-Moivres-theorem-not-valid-in-the-case-of-cos-x-I-sin-x-n-if-n-is-an-irrational-number), which might be helpful.

Comment: Also, you would be well-advised to format your question in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: De-Moivre's theorem fails for rationals such as $1/2$.  I believe your proof does show however that $\pi$ is not an integer.

Comment: Just to say, even though this proof failed it's a nice observation to come up with and if nothing else, it's an interesting sense in which $\pi$'s irrationality is somewhat nontrivial: if De Moivre had a rational extension then we could prove it like the above, but it doesn't because complex numbers are numerous so arbitrary powers of complex numbers can be multivalued.

Comment: I have no idea why anyone would downvote this.  It's an entirely sensible question.  And the OP plainly recognizes that it's unlikely to hold water and is just asking for someone to spot the leak.  Which, really, is not obvious.  Granted it ought to be properly formatted, but it is a good question (+1).

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your post, please check to make sure I didn't introduce any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) is:

$$\left( \cos x + i\sin x\right)^n = \cos (nx) + i\sin (nx).$$

It holds true for any real $x$ and any integer $n.$

You are suggesting there is a formula such as:

$$\left( \cos x + i\sin x\right)^{\frac{p}{q}} = \cos \left(\frac{p}{q}x\right) + i\sin \left(\frac{p}{q}x\right)$$

for integers $p$ and $q.$ However, this equation in general does not hold.

What is true is that

$$\left( \cos x + i\sin x\right)^{\frac{p}{q}} = \left( \left( \cos x + i\sin x\right)^{p} \right)^{\frac{1}{q}} = \left( \cos \left(px\right) + i\sin \left(px\right) \right) ^{\frac{1}{q}}$$

but unfortunately, in general,

$$\left( \cos \left(px\right) + i\sin \left(px\right) \right) ^{\frac{1}{q}} \neq \cos \left(\frac{p}{q}x\right) + i\sin \left(\frac{p}{q}x\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

De Moivre's formula only states that
$$
(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n=\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)
$$
when $n$ is an integer. So, you have no reason to assume that the equality $(\cos(2k\pi)+i\sin(2k\pi))^\pi=\cos(2k\pi^2)+i\sin(2k\pi^2)$ holds.

Comment: No, but the result holds for rational exponents with the expression being multivalued. E.g. if you were to raise to the power a/b then the expression can have b values with the result holding for the principal value.